# Complex differential geometric form of the Grothendieck–Hirzebruch–Riemann–Roch theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-operators

From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck%E2%80%93Hirzebruch%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem), it seems that there should be a differential geometric form of the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem with schemes replaced by complex manifolds and quasi-coherent sheaves replaced by vector bundles.  Unfortunately I don't know enough algebraic geometry to carryout the translation (for example I'm not sure what the pushforward of quasi-coherent sheafs corresponds to).

Does GHRR just amount to the Atiyah-Singer families index theorem for the fiberwise Dolbeault-Dirac operator?

Comment: A quasicoherent sheaf does not correspond to a vector bundle, in general: for one thing, quasicoherent sheaves can be infinite-dimensional, and for another, the dimension of a fibre can change from point to point. The pushforward is not easy to describe in terms of bundles, but in terms of sections, given a continuous map $f : X \to Y$, the pushforward sheaf $f_* \mathscr{F}$ is the sheaf on $Y$ such that the sections of $f_* \mathscr{F}$ over an open set $V$ are the same as the sections of $\mathscr{F}$ over $f^{-1} V$.

Comment: I don't really know the general algebraic geometry version, but for me Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch has always been the Atiyah-Singer index theorem for the (twisted) Dolbeault complex. See for example pages 151-153 of Berline-Getzler-Vergne's _Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators_.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton Thanks for your comment.  I'm familiar with HRR being a special case of the index theorem for the Clifford bundle of anti-holomorphic forms.  So my question is really if HRR generalizes to GHRR in the same way that the Dirac picture of HRR generalizes to a special case of the families index theorem that is equivalent to GHRR.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over a compact complex manifold. $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}(E))$ be the $i-$th sheaf cohomology, where $\mathcal{O}(E)$ is the sheaf of holomorphic sections of $E$. Then $$\sum(-1)^i\dim H^i(X, E)=\int_X td(X)ch(E)$$, where $td(X)$ is the total Todd class of M,  and $ch(E)$ is the Chern character of $E.$